# How to add multiple roles in wordpress during registration

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add multiple roles during registration, 
everything works except adding multiple user roles.

The code I use:

```php
$roles = array('wholesale_customer', 'retail_customer');

$userdata = array(
    'user_login'    =>  $username,
    'user_email'    =>  $email,
    'user_pass'     =>  $password,
    'user_url'      =>  $website,
    'first_name'    =>  $first_name,
    'last_name'     =>  $last_name,
    'nickname'      =>  $nickname,
    'description'   =>  $bio,
    'role'          =>  $roles  // want to add multiple roles such as editor,retailer
);

$user = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
```

Comment: means, i am trying to add the roles using array but it's not working, even i am trying to add manually in role parameter but still it's not working only, one roles is submitting

Comment: $roles = array('wholesale_customer', 'retail_customer'); Also, it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it this way?

```php
$userdata = array(
    'user_login'    => $username,
    'user_email'    => $email,
    'user_pass'     => $password,
    'user_url'      => $website,
    'first_name'    => $first_name,
    'last_name'     => $last_name,
    'nickname'      => $nickname,
    'description'   => $bio,
    'role'          => 'editor' // default
);

$userid = wp_insert_user( $userdata );

$user = new WP_User( $userid );

$user->add_role('retailer');
$user->add_role('customer');
// etc..
```

Comment: yes it's working, but it's adding default role = subscriber to

current I am getting ----  Subscriber, Wholesale Customer, Retail Customer.
Is it possible to store only wholesale_customer and retail only, exclude subscriber

Comment: have a look https://prnt.sc/sf8zox  , Is it possible to exclude subscriber role from this?

Comment: If I try my above code without the `add_role...` I get 1 role, namely 'editor' (Default).  
If I add `$user->add_role('retailer');`, an extra role is added